# I'm using cryptography in django and the problem is "it is not decrypting the value when using "from_db_value" function"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

settings.py:

```
ENCRYPTION_KEY=b'iHHJ-OlINvt7Ez7-js9JiAAy2I_hFJXWYhi8yIJZPCs='
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from .fields import EncryptedTextField

class all_License(models.Model):
    Lic_Id= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    LicenseKey= EncryptedTextField()
    ProductID= models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ClientID= models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ActivationStatus= models.BooleanField()
    ExpirationDate= models.DateField()
    IssuedDate= models.DateField()
    AssociatedDeviceID= models.IntegerField()
    AdditionalText= models.TextField()
```

fields.py:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class EncryptedTextField(models.TextField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cipher_suite = Fernet(settings.ENCRYPTION_KEY)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        cipher_text = self.cipher_suite.encrypt(value.encode('utf-8'))
        return cipher_text.decode()

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        decrypted_text = self.cipher_suite.decrypt(value.encode('utf-8')
        return decrypted_text.decode()
```

It just gives me "Invalid token" error while decrypting.it is just giving error in the from_db_value funtion.I have Tried this without django also and it is working fine even with the same key provided above. I don't know how to deal with this error. please help me!